# incrementing i with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, increment

I want to increment by i by 1 whenever the value is different for v_id.

```
    i = 1;
   
    for i in 1..10 loop 
      SELECT subject_details.NEXTVAL 
        INTO v_id 
        FROM dual;
    
      INSERT INTO employee (id, subject) 
           VALUES (i,v_id);

      i = i + 1;
    end loop;
```

what this does is

```
  id subject
    1  3647
    2  3647
    3  5678
    4  5678
    5  5678
```

but what I want is to increment the value of "i" by 1 whenever there is a change in value for "v_id"

```
id subject
1  3647
1  3647
2  5678
2  5678
2  5678
```

Comment: So `i = v_id - 999` ?

Comment: there value of v_id here is just an example. it can also be 74685 or 36495

Comment: I'd love to know how calling a sequence.nextval returns the same value over successive iterations

Comment: it is because of the Function subject_details that is written for this case.

Comment: do you really want to loop exactly 10 times? or do you want to loop until the `SELECT` is done returning values?

Comment: offtopic: why `SELECT subject_details.NEXTVAL INTO v_id FROM dual;` instead of `v_id := subject_details.nextval`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this bit of code? Is it a learning exercise for a class/training course you're in? I ask because if this were meant for production code, there are better ways of handling the task.

Comment: @Boneist this is a code from my production env.

Comment: I would scrap the loop and look to take Gordon's dense_rank idea and use it in an `insert into .... select ...` statement instead. You're probably also looping through a cursor, which will be slow. Don't do row-by-row processing (e.g. looping through a cursor) when you can do set-based processing (e.g. a single SQL statement)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by subject) 
from t;
```

If the values can be interleaved, then you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_subject = subject then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id)
from (select t.*,
             lag(subject) over (order by id) as prev_subject
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: but i want these values to be inserted in the table. can dense_Rank be used in insert statement ?

Comment: @newintodev . . . Yes.  Any `select` statement works with `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

While there are good suggestions offered, I think they mostly miss your biggest mistake. I believe that is a miss understanding of pl/sql scoping rules. Somewhere in tour code (before what you posted) you defined a variable i then created i as the index variable of a FOR loop. The problem you face is that due to scoping rules ***these are not the same variable***. According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1515):   (also see [demonstration here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38fba6e42db424892574b5632bea790b))

> for *index* name  
>  Name for the implicitly declared integer variable that is
> local to the FOR LOOP statement. Statements outside the loop cannot
> reference index. Statements inside the loop can reference index, but
> cannot change its value. After the FOR LOOP statement runs, index is
> undefined.

There are a couple other issues with you process:

- In Oracle the assignment operator is := not =; (I assume this is just
  a typo).
- In each loop iteration you run "subject_details.NEXTVAL", and
  subsequently insert that result into your table. Doing so will
  increment the value every time. Thus you cannot produce your desired
  output - nor your claimed output.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
j = 1;
v_id_copy = 0;
for i in 1..10 loop 
SELECT subject_details.NEXTVAL INTO v_id FROM dual;
if(v_id_copy==0) then
v_id_copy = v_id;
elseif (v_id_copy != v_id) then
j=j+1;
v_copy_id=v_id;
endif
insert into employee (id,subject) values (j,v_id)
end loop;
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria, welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may answer the question, you might improve it by providing context: how/why does this solve the issue? What was different about what you did from the asker that worked?